# Initialize PictureBox before Form Load event

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

In the Form Load event I bring data from a database, all I want to do is to display a PictureBox which contains a GIF with a loading animation, but I want to do it after the data is loaded from the database, some idea?

Comment: What have you tried so far?
Do you want to display the loading animation until the GIF is loaded?

Comment: Your question shows no effort and does not make sense.  You want to display a loading animation `after the data is loaded`? The form does not show until *after* the form load event so you are going about it wrong. Read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Have the form open normally, then read the data in a background thread.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to display a loading gif while the data is retrieved from the database.

Instead of putting all the code inside the Form Load, you can try to first display the PictureBox and then start a new thread that loads the data. Once the data is retrieved, you can remove the gif.